# libGDX's stops being able to catch cursor after entering fullscreen

Tags: java, kotlin, libgdx, mouse-cursor

I'm writing a little `libGDX` game. Capturing the cursor with **`setCursorCatched(boolean)`** works perfectly at first (hides the cursor symbol and won't let me escape the window) but then breaks:

- After I enter fullscreen with `F` and then exit with `G`, the cursor can *escape on all sides*.
- After I enter fullscreen with `F` with 2 monitors, I can also *escape to my 2nd monitor*.
- Using `setCursorPosition` every frame does not mitigate this issue.

Full minimal reproducible example (see also [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67422891/2111778)):

```kotlin
package xjcl.extracredits2020

import com.badlogic.gdx.*

class RangeAnxietyGame : ApplicationAdapter() {
    override fun create() {
        Gdx.input.apply { isCursorCatched = true }
    }

    override fun render() {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.F))
            Gdx.graphics.setFullscreenMode(Gdx.graphics.displayMode)
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.G))
            Gdx.graphics.setWindowedMode(1280, 720)
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.ESCAPE))
            Gdx.app.exit()

        Gdx.input.setCursorPosition(Gdx.graphics.width/2, Gdx.graphics.height/2)
    }
}
```

**Is there any way to force the cursor to stay captured by the `libGDX` window?**

Comment: Are you using LWJGL3? I would try that if you haven't yet. To switch it, modify the gradle dependencies to point at `lwjgl3` instead of `lwjgl` artifacts. Then in your desktop launcher class, change any class starting with `Lwjgl` with `Lwjgl3` and fix all your imports.

Comment: Switching to `lwjgl3` fixed the issue entirely, wow! (Note to future readers: `setCursorPosition` should not be used)

Comment: `lwjgl3` also fixed the weird flashing I got when closing a windowed or fullscreen game. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### As suggested by `@Tenfour04`, switching from `lwjgl` to `lwjgl3` eliminates the issue!

In `build.gradle` change the first into the second block:

```
api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
```

```
api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl3:$gdxVersion"
```

Also adjust your imports (e.g. in the `DesktopLauncher` class):

```java
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
```

```java
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration;
```

In my case I also needed to update the config of the `DesktopLauncher`:

```java
LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
config.samples = 8;
config.height = 720;
config.width = 1280;
config.vSyncEnabled = true;
new LwjglApplication(new RangeAnxietyGame(), config);
```

```java
Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration config = new Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration();
config.setBackBufferConfig(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0, 8);
config.setWindowedMode(1280, 720);
config.useVsync(true);
new Lwjgl3Application(new RangeAnxietyGame(), config);
```